global sections of type (a,b) divisors on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$
For example, let $D$ be a type $(a,b)$ divisor on $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, I would like to compute $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1, \mathcal{O}(D))$.
Since on $\mathbb{P}^n$, we know $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(m))$ is a vector space which has a basis consists of homogeneous monomonials of degree $m$ in $x_0,\ldots,x_n$. So I guess something similar happens for $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$. I take $D_1=\{pt\} \times \mathbb{P}^1$ and $D_2=\mathbb{P}^1 \times \{pt\}$, then take $aD_1+bD_2$ to be the type $(a,b)$ divisor. Then compute $H^0(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1,aD_1+bD_2)$ (I use $x,y$ and $z,w$ to be the coordinates on two $\mathbb{P}^1$'s), then I get $\{x^iy^j| i+j=a\} \cup \{z^kw^l|k+l=b\}$. But it does not looks right (it is not even a vector space).
If someone could give a right calculation or hint?

Have you tried to compute via the sheaf condition (equivalently, Cech cohomology) yet? You should find that fairly tractable.

I think maybe Kunneth formula will give me the answer, that union should be a tensor right?

Yes, Kunneth will give the result, and you'll need to take the tensor product of the vector spaces, but how do you prove Kunneth? One of the more straightforward ways to do it in algebraic geometry is via Cech cohomology.
